# How to set up routing of https to proxy server on client

Tags: iptables, proxy, ppp

There are are lot of excellent answers to this question which involve setting iptables routes on the router. However I need to set up the iptables routes on the client.

I'm working on an embedded system. This is connected to the internet using ppp and a GPRS modem. The system runs an application that makes https requests via libcurl.

I now need to route those https requests through a transparent https proxy server hosted somewhere on the internet. I've set up an https proxy with squid and ssl_bump, and I've verified that it's all working as expected.

There are various ways of routing the https requests through the proxy e.g. I can rebuild the application and configure libcurl to use the proxy server via CURLOPT_PROXY. But I'm wondering if it might be simpler and more flexible to set up a route to forward everything sent to the HTTPS port to the proxy.

The closest question I've seen is [How do I configure a transparent proxy where the proxy server is remote?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314262/141599) but this requires the route to contain the IP address of the client. As this is a GPRS connection which will come and go, the IP address will be unknown and will change from time to time.

Comment: I don't know about possible ssl complications. To route a specific port elsewhere, it involves identifying the traffic (usually with iptables -j MARK and/or CONNMARK) and selecting an alternate route (ip rule fwmark + ip route table) for the identified traffic. While this works fine for incoming or routed traffic, for locally initiated outgoing traffic usually the wrong source ip gets chosen so it has also to be nated. So this is a bit messy and there are corner cases with udp. If you can avoid this, you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libcurl respect environnement variables **http_proxy** **https_proxy**

So this is very simple :

```
export http_proxy=http://yourproxy.example.com:3128/
export https_proxy=http://yourproxy.example.com:3128/
./my-application-exe
```

source:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html

Comment: Apologies for the late acceptance - I used this answer and it's been working in production with no issues.